# Were magical creatures and magic north of The Wall affected when dragons returned?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the show it is evident that

> With the rebirth of dragons, magic (or at least eastern
>   magic) seems to be slowly making its way back into the world

Warging is also considered as a magic and it seems it was already strong and popular among the wildlings before the birth of the dragons.

Were northern magics beyond the wall already strong, or did the rebirth of dragons give them a boost in some way?

Are Giants, White Walkers & Children of the Forest just non-human races, or they are also magical in some way and get a power boost when dragons are born?

Comment: Magic was part of the world for whole time but it gets stronger and more common I guess.

Comment: AFAWK, Children of the forest were creatures of westeros before the arrival of the Andals and the first men. So i won't go as far as tying their existence with dragons. Walkers though we don't know much about them, and mind you i mean the real walkes not the dead people reborn into zombies. Giants are just simple creatures i don't see anything special about them. 
There are running theories that the universe of westeros is guided by balance between dark and light, fire and ice and therefore with the coming back of dragons the dark and ice powers need to fight back to maintain balance.

Comment: “Are Giants, White Walkers & Children of the Forest just non-human races, or they are also magical in some way” — can’t they be both?

Comment: If they weren't affected, it seems awfully coincidental that the Walkers returned around the same time the dragons hatched. Giants are a dying race and haven't really made a comeback, and it's debatable whether or not the Children are nearly extinct or just in hiding. The Greenseer DID send them out to look for Bran, however. And all of this started after dragons came back into the world. IMHO, there's definitely a connection between all of it.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You are right but what I meant was if they possess any magical abilities were those enhanced after birth of dragons

Answer (score 4):

Northern magic has been boosted, but I doubt it was caused by the rebirth of dragons.  Rather the rebirth of dragons seems to have been caused by the recent surge in magic, much like like northern magic in general.  I would say the recent surge in magic could be attributed to several things, here are my top three:

The red comet.  While it only became visible recently, we can assume it was drawing closer to the fire and ice world, and now that it is 'overhead' magic is at its strongest. Or, it too is the result of the surge in magic, though this seems unlikely.

Natural ebb and flow of this world.  Magic rises and recedes and this is the way of things and always has been.

The Night's King.  His rise could also have triggered the rise of magic, possibly to provide the means to resist him.  The question here is, why didn't he rise sooner?  If it is the same Night's King of legend, he has been around for a long time, so why now?  If he is a new figure being mistaken for the Night's King, it begs the same question, why now?  If he 'unleashed' or 'harnessed' some new power, I would think GRRM would have hinted at it by now.  I thought about giving the Others their own category, but, although they seem to have somehow bestowed the Night's King's power on him, he appears to spearhead their advance.  It's possible they have done something to open the flood gates of magic, but their absence from the shows and obscurity in the books tells me, no, they are not at the root of the rise in magic.

As far as other creatures/species, I haven't noticed information pointing to giants being magical, though they may have been the result of magic, like dragons.  The wildings don't appear awed by giants so it doesn't seem as if they have become more numerous during this time of high magic.
I would guess the Children of the Forest are magical.  The tales and myths of man that touch on the children are wrapped in magic.  Also, they are said to sing the song of earth in the True Tongue, which *sounds* like magic.  But I wouldn't say their magic is increasing, rather it appears to nearly be finished.  Of the six children known to man, none have been reported to produce magic on a scale with what they are said to have done during the epoch-call great floods down to kill the first men.  They harness magic, but the tone of the GRRM's writing makes it sound as if it is the same magic they have always possessed and their dwindling numbers is in lock-step with their magic dwindling.

The White Walkers or Wight Walkers (as some call them) appear to be a direct result of the rise in power/magic by the Night's King and the Others (I assert their mere return as a recent rise in the King's power, or why didn't he return sooner?)

I would say the Others sound the most tightly bound with magic, but I would not go so far as to suggest they are magical in nature.  I like the idea of the red comet as the cause of magic in the world.

Answer (score 2):

The children of the forest at least are definitely magical in some way. They possess both the powers of worging and green dreams. It's unclear however if they were affected at all by the presence of dragons. 
  As for the white walkers, they do seem to be more active recently than they have been for thousands of years. However that started befor the dragons hatched, and we don't know enough about the white walkers to know if their powers have increased at all since the birth of dragons. 
  It's possible that the birth of dragons only affect Fire magic. Most of definite the examples of magic increasing since the birth of dragons is somehow related to Fire Magic. For example the priest the red God and the pyromancer. 
  It's also possible that dragon  are a symptom not the cause of The Rebirth of magic. Remember that people have been trying to hatch Dragon for hundreds of years with little or no success. It's possible they were unable to have dragon's because  magic was weak then and now as magic grows stronger dragons can be hatch.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear so as Qhorin tells Stonesnake.

> There was no question of riding double. Stonesnake offered to lay in wait for the pursuit and surprise them when they came. Perhaps he could take a few of them with him down to hell. Qhorin refused. "If any man in the Night's Watch can make it through the Frostfangs alone and afoot, it is you, brother. You can go over mountains that a horse must go around. Make for the Fist. Tell Mormont what Jon saw, and how. **Tell him that the old powers are waking, that he faces giants and wargs and worse. Tell him that the trees have eyes again.**"
>   <sub>A Clash of Kings, Jon VIII</sub>

Whether this is because of the Others returning, the dragons have been re-birthed or something else is unclear but it appears something has woken the magic beyond the Wall again. Note though that the Others were first seen beyond the Wall before the dragons were re-birthed and although they appear to be a separate species they do seem to be magical in nature. As such it would appear as though magic had never truly left the true north.